# JavaScript Display Variables onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to populate several divs with information stored in variables that change onclick of an image. This is some of the code inside my  tag:

```
function getName(name){
    document.getElementById('show_name').innerHTML = name
}

function getDetailsForBill(){
     getName('Bill Gates'); 
     getMotto('Bills motto'); 
     getImage ('<img src="http://www.somepage.com/images/team/bill.jpg" />');
}
```

This is how I use the onclick:

```
<img src="bill.jpg" onclick="getDetailsForBill();" />
```

This is how I try to show the information associated with each person:

```
<div id="show_name"></div>
```

However, the information does not show up. What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: `getName()`... Sets a "name" for an element?

Comment: Blender, I don't get any errors on the page.

Comment: Jared, yes, I have about 20 people and each one is a function where the parameter defined within the function, i.e. getName(name) is hard-coded and that function is called only for that person.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/LEUPc/) Could you make a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem, please?

Comment: minitech, do you mean does the image link to an external page, in which case no. Yes I will make a jsFiddle no problem.

Comment: Here, thanks http://jsfiddle.net/uAqgu/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you have shown, so the problem is somewhere in something that you haven't shown.

Here is a working example, if you compare it to your code, you might spot a difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/bkyFb/

---

#### Edit:

There is a syntax error in the code in the fiddle that you posted. You end the `getDetailsForBill` function with `}}` instead of `}`.

Comment: I want to display all the different information using the same method. For instance, function getName(name){
    document.getElementById('show_name').innerHTML = name
}
function getMotto(motto){
    document.getElementById('show_motto').innerHTML = motto
}
function getImage(image){
    document.getElementById('show_image').innerHTML = image
}

Comment: @TheShadowbyte: Yes, I realise that. I showed that showing one piece of information does work just fine, so showing the other pieces would just be a matter of repeating the code. The code that you have shown does work, so it's not possible to find the error from the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have only one div with id='show_name' on the page?

Second, try to change getDetailsForBill() to:

```
function getDetailsForBill(){
     getName('Bill Gates'); 
     //getMotto('Bills motto'); 
     //getImage ('<img src="http://www.somepage.com/images/team/bill.jpg" />');
}
```

Does this work fine and display a name?

Comment: Yes, I only have 1 such div on the page. I tried commenting it out and it still doesn't work. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/uAqgu/1/

Comment: @TheShadowbyte: When you load that example there is a syntax error. You have `}}` ending the `getDetailsForBill` function, change that to `}`.

Comment: Okay so, when I do <div id="show_name"></div> it shows the name but when I do
<div id="show_name"></div>
<div id="show_motto"></div>
<div id="show_image"></div> for all of them it does not show any of them.

Comment: Check my version http://jsfiddle.net/uAqgu/12/ (I removed a curly brace and added two div for motto and image).